# «Хожу, пригибая колени(,) я»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, значение-слов, словосочетания, деепричастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая, если предложение построено так?

*Хожу, пригибая колени(,) я.*

Comment: Как бы предложение ни было построено, деепричастный оборот выделяется с двух сторон.

Comment: Почему я не вижу галочки для принятия ответа?

Comment: Потому что ответа нету.

Comment: И «пригибая колени» нету. Изобретать невредно, однако...

Comment: Разве нельзя ходить, пригибая колени, чтобы казаться ниже ростом, например? Как тогда это выразить?

Comment: Ходить-то можно.Можно ли **говорить** так - вот вопрос. Честно говоря - не знаю. В текстах встречается крайне редко - и не в слишком авторитетных. Колени, судя по всему, можно **согнуть**, а вот **пригнуть** - непонятно.

Comment: В поэзии разве что. "Я куда-то улетаю, словно дерево с листа"(с)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Указанная запятая безусловно нужна. Здесь я однозначно поддерживаю *Людмилу*: "Как бы предложение ни было построено, деепричастный оборот выделяется с двух сторон".

Деепричастный оборот, как правило, **обособляется** (выделяется запятыми) независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому.
[Деепричастные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113)

2. *И «пригибая колени» нету. Изобретать невредно, однако... – shampar...*

Хочу возразить. Вот что пишет Даль:
[**пригибать**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/333726/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%93%D0%98%D0%91%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC) или пригинать, тамб. пригнибать; пригнуть что, нагибать, сгибать, преклонять, гнуть, гнести вершину к низу; подгибать... **Пригибать колено**, приседать.

*Граф Понятовский мог служить отличной моделью для картины. Красота её нарушалась только Шридманом, производившим слегка комическое впечатление: высокий офицер так низко [**пригибал колени**](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=625097&p=23), что казался на целую голову ниже, чем был на самом деле* (Грегор Самаров. На пороге трона).

*Он был юн и прекрасен верой. Он склонялся ко мне тем ниже, чем ниже я **пригибал колени*** (М. Волошин. Судьба Верхарна).

*Чепурин, без фуражки, с закатанными рукавами белой рубахи, косил размашисто, низко пуская косу, чуть [**пригибая колени**](http://www.gorenka.org/index.php/chitalnya-46/6018-nosov-e-i-shumit-lugovaya-ovsyanitsa)* ([Е. И. Носов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). Шумит луговая овсяница [часть третья]. Библиотека юношества, 1977).
Это предложение также приведено в статье "[косить](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ZQO2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=JHae9ZwNOy&sig=ACfU3U1ZWYrl3xLY7y5szCMX2xMK18sgzQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiI8Lyd-9_lAhXksYsKHfc4AV4Q6AEwBXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8&f=false)" в качестве примера (Ю. Гребнева. Словарь омонимов, омоформ и омографов русского языка).

Да, выражение встречается нечасто, употребляется особенно, но говорить, что оно неверно, — никак нельзя. Ходить, пригибая колени, — это ходить приседая. Так можно, думаю, описать передвижение человека, наложившего в штаны, или физкультурное упражнение, или кузнечика, сломавшего ногу.

Comment: @Лия Спасибо, Лия, за оценку моего ответа. Мне было _действительно интересно_ провести некоторое "словосочетательное" расследование (от него ведь другие участники почему-то сразу отказались).

Answer (score 1):

Это про Ваш случай:

> VII. Запятые при обстоятельственных оборотах § 153. Запятыми
>   выделяются:
>
> 1. Деепричастия, как с пояснительными словами, так и без них, кроме таких одиночных деепричастий и деепричастных оборотов, которые
>      **> примыкают непосредственно к сказуемому и по своему значению
>      приближаются к наречию**, например:
>      Вы и в залу входите танцуя.

Что касается "пригибания колен", то пригибают обычно что-то вниз (голову чаще всего) или что-то к чему-то. А вот колени, как уже заметили в комментариях, сгибают.

Comment: Ещё могут быть подогнутые колени. Но можно ли ходить с ними, затрудняюсь сказать. Во всяком случае, я бы сказал гораздо скорее "хожу, подгибая колени", чем "пригибая".